# How to create text from dataframe by two categorical columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to take a filtered database table of text values and create a text report where there are variable number of lines (created by combining several columns for each row in the filtered table) with headings and sub-headings that are created from 2 other columns in the table.

This is to send to an rmarkdown document for creating a word or html doc. I have tried converting to list and using by() with paste to combine columns but cannot get what I want.

```
df=data.frame(cat1=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
  
  cat2=c("D","D","E","D","F","D","G","G"),
  
  text1=c("text1","text2","text3","text4","text5","text6","text7","text8"),
  
  text2=c("text9","text10","text11","text12","text13","text14","text15","text16"))
```

I want something like:

> ### A: D:
>
> text1, text9
>
> text2, text10
>
> ### A: E:
>
> text3, text11
>
> ### B: D:
>
> text4, text12
>
> ### B: F:
>
> text5, text13
>
> ### C: D:
>
> text6, text14
>
> ### C: G:
>
> text7, text15
>
> text8, text 16

I get complicated lists that I cannot parse.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that with `aggregate` and `paste`

```
T1 = aggregate(df$text1, list(df$cat1, df$cat2), paste, collapse = ", ")
T2 = aggregate(df$text2, list(df$cat1, df$cat2), paste, collapse = ", ")
T1$x = paste(T1$x, T2$x, sep=", ")
T1
  Group.1 Group.2                            x
1       A       D  text1, text2, text9, text10
2       B       D                text4, text12
3       C       D                text6, text14
4       A       E                text3, text11
5       B       F                text5, text13
6       C       G text7, text8, text15, text16
```

Comment: Something happened to my blockquotes and lines got concatenated.  I have edited my original to fix it so that lines are not collapsed.  I get closer to what I want with `df$line=paste(df$text1,df$text2,sep=", "` and then `df_ag=aggregate(df$line, by=list(df$cat1,df$cat2), identity)`.  I Can then use the two group variables for Headers and the indexes for line number of text to print in each section.  Any better ideas?

Comment: Any idea why the `aggregate(..., identity)` command produces an x column with indexes of line numbers from original data frame rather than the text? `aggregate(..., print)` loses the groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution:

```
for (i in unique(df$cat1)) {
  cat(i,"\n")
  for (j in unique(df[df$cat1==i,"cat2"])) {
    cat(paste(" ",j),"\n")
    for (k in df$line[df$cat1==i & df$cat2==j])
    cat(paste("   ",k),"\n")
  }
}
```

Which gives:

```
A 
  D 
    text1, text9 
    text2, text10 
  E 
    text3, text11 
B 
  D 
    text4, text12 
  F 
    text5, text13 
C 
  D 
    text6, text14 
  G 
    text7, text15 
    text8, text16
```